# Postfix capture messages exceeding limit

Tags: centos, email, postfix, filter

Is it possible to capture/filter messages that are exceeding the limit that has been set in the postfix configuration, and forward the captured mails to an external id?

thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** We do not want to increase the global limit, since, we want the limit to be set only to certain specific mail accounts.

**EDIT 2 :** External/third party tools can be suggested

Comment: Say the limit you want to define for some email accounts is `x`. set `message_size_limit` to `y` (where `y > x`). Write a [milter](https://pythonhosted.org/pymilter/) to capture/hold the messages exceeding `x`.

Comment: cool @clement , but how do we set  _the limit for some email accounts is x_ is it even possible on postfix?

Comment: You can do that in milter